# C# WinForms How to display Values from List in a Graph

Tags: c#, forms, list, graph

So I have a List in a List with Timespans that I need to be shown in some kind of Graph, maybe something like a coordinate system with an x and y axis. I already found something that is called chart from the data category but I don't understand how I'm supposed to use it. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82jnryBxsnI) for the beginning. If you still have problems after you wrote some code, just edit your post and write a comment

Comment: Yes, Chart is what you want. You also need to know just how your graph is supposed to look!? Lines, points, columns, curves??? You want to set the  `XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime` for your series and add the data points like this: `yourSeriesS.Points.AddXY(someBaseDate.Add(yourTimespanValuet), your y-data-value);`. Also set the format of the axislabels to maybe: `yourXaxis.LabelStyle.Format = "hh:mm";`